# How to get the custom taxonomy terms' names, link and image coming from acf field

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am building a website in Wordpress and I have a custom post type called "travels" with a custom taxonomy called "collections". Inside the taxonomy collection there are different terms, such as "Collection 1", "Collection 2", "Collection 3" etc.

What I want to obtain is a loop displaying all the terms' names, links to their archive page and image (this one come from an acf field called "taxonomy_image").

All of these datas should be retrieved inside this structure:

```
<a href="here goes the link to the term's archive page"><div class="col-3 py-4 coverbackground" style="background:url(here goes the taxonomy image from the acf field); height:300px;">

                <div class="row whiteborders h-100  mx-auto">
                    <div class="col-12 align-self-center">
                        <h2 class="text-center text-white">here goes the term's title</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>




  </div></a>
```

I hope I've been clear enough, because I'm new to this and I really do not know how to handle this problem. Any kind of suggestion will really be appreciated. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing may not work is the image, cause you have to set your acf image field `Return Value` to `Image URL`.

**Tested and working**

```
  <?php
   $terms = get_terms([
      'taxonomy' => 'collections',
  ]);
  foreach($terms as $term) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
    <div class="col-3 py-4 coverbackground" style="background:url(<?php the_field('taxonomy_image', $term); ?>); height:300px;">
    <div class="row whiteborders h-100  mx-auto">
      <div class="col-12 align-self-center">
          <h2 class="text-center text-white"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <?php } ?>
```

If you use img array then this is what you need:

```
  <?php
   $terms = get_terms([
      'taxonomy' => 'collections',
  ]);
  foreach($terms as $term) {
  $image = get_field('taxonomy_image', $term);?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
    <div class="col-3 py-4 coverbackground" style="background:url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>); height:300px;">
    <div class="row whiteborders h-100  mx-auto">
      <div class="col-12 align-self-center">
          <h2 class="text-center text-white"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: just one more question: my image is set as an Array field. Is there a way it can be retrieved this way? Or does it need to be an Url? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, I added the array way at the bottom

Comment: It seems like I can't make it work...Where should I add those two strings?